# To drop an index with psycopg2 takes effect before or after commit?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I'm doing a python script to insert several data into a postgresql database.

Following the postgresql [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/populate.html) in order to speed up the load process my script has this sort of structure

- Connect to the database and create a cursor
- Drop all the indexes
- Load all the data using the 'copy' command
- Recreate back all the indexes
- Commit and close of the cursor and connection (only commit in the whole script)

So my question is: Is dropping the indexes before the commit, taking any effect in terms of speeding up the loading, or not ?

Comment: you drop indexes for fast `COPY` - it is not connected to before/after commit (sorry - I dont understand the question)

Comment: yes, it is connected at the beginning of the script. Going to fix that to avoid misunderstandings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commit` just commits any ongoing transaction in progress to your database.

What you actually are asking if whether dropping indexes and then copying within the same transaction will provide the same speedup as first dropping indexes in one transaction and then copying data in a new transaction.

The direct quote from [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/populate.html) says that:

> If you are adding large amounts of data to an existing table, it might be a win to drop the indexes, load the table, and then recreate the indexes. **Of course, the database performance for other users might suffer during the time the indexes are missing.** One should also think twice before dropping a unique index, since the error checking afforded by the unique constraint will be lost while the index is missing.

The bolded part indirectly tells that you should commit after dropping the indexes, as dropping indexes without committing (completing the transaction) should not have any impact on other users of the database.

So the solution should be something along these lines:

drop your indexes, commit, copy the data, create new indexes and commit again.

Note that as you split your transaction into two transactions, you lose atomicity. I.e. it's possible that your indexes are dropped, but no data is copied (if power or network for example is lost during the copying transaction) and the indexes would never be recreated.

Comment: I'd say the opposite. from the quote you should `begin; drop indexes; copy; recreate indexes; commit;` so other users would continue using old indexes, not suffering slowere queries

Comment: The quote indicated that the price you pay for faster copy is lack of indexes for a period of time. I.e. if you do all in one transaction, dropping indexes will not improve performance of `copy`. (this would have to benchmarked to make sure, but to me it does make sense.), but that's what the docs currently are saying. I see no reason why the docs would clearly indicate that there's a trade-off between usability and speed in this case, if you could do it all in one transaction.

Comment: @VaoTsun  Dropping indexes will take a strong lock on the table.  No one will be able to continue using the old indexes, as they will be locked out until the drop is committed.