# how to drop and create postgres index with Python

Tags: python, postgresql, indexing, psycopg2

I am writing a Python application which involves loading hundreds of millions of records to a table in batches. I noticed the load speed slowed down dramatically since an index created on this table recently. From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902428/to-drop-an-index-with-psycopg2-takes-effect-before-or-after-commit), it seems the common practice is to drop the index, load data and recreate index. However the job is scheduled as daily job. In order to automate the process, I would need to drop and create index using Python in the same application. Can't seem to find how to do it with Python and psycopg2 though. That post didn't have any code either. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: If you are adding rows rather than replacing them, you should consider partitioning.  Dropping a 10 billion row index just to recreate it later as a 10.2 billion row index is probably not a usable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just execute the sql for dropping and creating the indexes, as you do with the insert query you use to load the data?

```
cursor.execute("DROP INDEX <name>")
...
load data here
...
cursor.execute("CREATE INDEX ...")
```